# FluentValidation Custom Function within Validator Class

Tags: vb.net, fluentvalidation

Using this [example](https://fluentvalidation.net/start#including-rules) from the FluentValidation website, I'm converting the concept to VB.NET using my own classes. The part in interest to my issue is the `Must(BeOver18)`, which calls the `protected` function. Note that this call doesn't pass a parameter to `BeOver18`:

```
public class PersonAgeValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>  {
  public PersonAgeValidator() {
    RuleFor(x => x.DateOfBirth).Must(BeOver18);
  }

  protected bool BeOver18(DateTime date) {
    //...
  }
}
```

I created my own validator class in VB.NET like this, using the same principal as above but instead for a function called `CustomerExists`:

```
Public Class ContractValidator
    Inherits AbstractValidator(Of ContractDTO)

    Public Sub New()

        RuleSet("OnCreate",
            Sub()
                RuleFor(Function(x) x.CustomerID).NotEmpty
                ' Compiler error here:
                ' BC30455   Argument not specified for parameter 'customerID'.....
                RuleFor(Function(x) x.CustomerID).Must(CustomerExists)
            End Sub
        )

    End Sub


    Protected Function CustomerExists(customerID As Integer) As Boolean

        Return CustomerService.Exists(customerID)

    End Function

End Class
```

**ISSUE:** The line in VB.NET with `.Must(CustomerExists)` is giving the "Argument not specified for parameter 'customerID'..." compiler error. The C# example does not pass a parameter to `BeOver18`. I tried an additional anonymous in-line function to try to pass ContractDTO.CustomerID, but it doesn't work as it's not recognized:

```
' This won't work:
RuleFor(Function(x) x.CustomerID).Must(CustomerExists(Function(x) x.CustomerID))
```

I'm at a loss on how the C# example can call it's function without a parameter, but the VB.NET conversion cannot. This is where i need help.

Comment: Does it work if you try `RuleFor(Function(x) x.CustomerID).Must(AddressOf CustomerExists)`

Comment: That will compile, but fails at runtime. I set an invalid CustomerID to the ContractDTO and validation still passed, so the CustomerExists() function in the validator wasn't getting called properly.

Comment: If the call to the method is successful, it may be time to take a look at what's going on using the debugger. Especially since that correction is only responsible for passing the customer id along to the method. First step would be confirming the correct Id is indeed sent.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. It did work. I didn't call validation by the named RuleSet. Once I did that, my custom function was called, and the proper (invalid) CustomerID was passed to that function, and validation failed as expected. Add as an answer and I'll mark it. AddressOf is what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CustomerExists` function needs to be treated as a delegate. In order to do that, change the following:

Original

```vb
 RuleFor(Function(x) x.CustomerID).Must(CustomerExists)
```

Update

```vb
RuleFor(Function(x) x.CustomerID).Must(AddressOf CustomerExists)
```